# CSS/CSS3 - How to make background-color in table row without spaces between table-cells?

Tags: html, css, smarty

I have table and I have to use css rule to separate table-cells (`border-spacing: 10px;border-collapse: separate;`), but when I to put background-color in table row, then it shows this color in each table-cell with 10px spaces. Is there a way how to workaround it. I have to put this background color in row without spaces ? Thank you very much.

HTML:

```
<table style="border-spacing: 10px;border-collapse: separate;">
                <tr><td style="text-align:left;"><b style="color: #32598A;">Course Name</b></td><td style="text-align:left;"><b style="color: #32598A;">Days</b></td><td style="text-align:left;"><b style="color: #32598A;">Start</b></td><td style="text-align:left;"><b style="color: #32598A;">End</b></td><td style="text-align:left;"><b style="color: #32598A;">Location</b></td><td style="text-align:left;"><b style="color: #32598A;">Price</b></td></tr>
                {section name=open_trainings loop=$open_trainings_all}
                            <tr><td style="text-align:left;"><a style="color: #5DA9DD;" href="/{$country}/{$lang}/{$open_trainings_all[open_trainings].CategoryID}_{if $open_trainings_all[open_trainings].CategoryID == "15"}{foreach from=$category_15 item=CAT}{$CAT.friendlyTitle}{/foreach}{/if}{if $open_trainings_all[open_trainings].CategoryID == "16"}{foreach from=$category_16 item=CAT}{$CAT.friendlyTitle}{/foreach}{/if}/{$open_trainings_all[open_trainings].Code}_{$open_trainings_all[open_trainings].friendlyTitle}.html?do=course"><b>{$open_trainings_all[open_trainings].Title}</b></a></td>
                            <td style="text-align:left;">{$open_trainings_all[open_trainings].Days}</td>
                            <td style="text-align:left;">{$open_trainings_all[open_trainings].LocalDateStart}</td>
                            <td style="text-align:left;">{$open_trainings_all[open_trainings].LocalDateEnd}</td>
                            <td style="text-align:left;"><img src="/storage/images/flags/flags2/{$open_trainings_all[open_trainings].Flag}" alt="flag" /><br />({$open_trainings_all[open_trainings].Country})<br />{$open_trainings_all[open_trainings].Location}</td>
                       {if strpos($smarty.server.REQUEST_URI,'/us/')}
                            <td style="text-align:left;">{$open_trainings_all[open_trainings].Priceus} USD</td>
                       {else}
                            <td style="text-align:left;">{$open_trainings_all[open_trainings].Priceau} AUD</td>
                       {/if}
                            <td style="text-align:left;"><a style="color: #5DA9DD;" href="/{$country}/{$lang}/7_contacts.html?form=3&acode={$open_trainings_all[open_trainings].Code}&l={$open_trainings_all[open_trainings].Location}&d={$open_trainings_all[open_trainings].StartDate}">Registration</a></td></tr>
                {/section}
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Tables have many caveats when it comes to their presentation. You encountered one of them.

One of the workarounds is to collapse the cells, and use additional empty rows to separate successive rows.

```
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;"> <!-- No spaces any longer -->
    <tr>
        <td>Cell A1</td>
        <td>Cell A2</td>
        <td>Cell A3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="separator"> <!-- Those are the new horizontal spaces -->
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell B1</td>
        <td>Cell B2</td>
        <td>Cell B3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[This page](http://techdebtmodel.com/) shows an example of a more complicated layout.

Answer (score 1):

you need to put this `<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-spacing: 10px;border-collapse: separate;">`

reference link [[http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_cellpadding.asp]](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_cellpadding.asp%5d)

Comment: `border-collapse: collapse;` should be sufficient.